# How do enable panelizer support for a custom entity?

Tags: entities, panels

I've programmatically created an entity. I'd like to panelize it. What plugins do I need to write to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just create a **PanelizerEntity** Plugin in your module.
Ex if your entity type id (or machine name) is '**course**'. Create a file **PanelizerCourse.php** in *your_module/src/Plugin/PanelizerEntity/*

This file should extends PanelizerEntityBase like that:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\your_module\Plugin\PanelizerEntity;

use Drupal\panelizer\Plugin\PanelizerEntityBase;

/**
 * Panelizer entity plugin for integrating with courses.
 *
 * @PanelizerEntity("course")
 */
class PanelizerCourse extends PanelizerEntityBase {

}
```